# Why is there always "round trip" in partitioned DocumentDB collection?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am issuing a request like below to partitioned DocumentDB collection. The collection is partitioned for future purpose, but there is only single value for the partition key at this moment.

`{
    "query": "SELECT * FROM r where r.id = @id",
    "parameters": [
        {"name": "@id", "value": "4a97b4fe-cbf7-4e7c-be50-e90d3ce7bc14"}
    ]
}`

The first page returns empty with some `x-ms-continuation` as `#PKRID:1`. As I go through next pages specifying different `x-ms-continuation` header, eventually the proper body returns around `#PKRID:16` (16th page). It seems this is called "round trip" in DocumentDB portal, because each paging requires network round trip.

Questions :

1. Is this normal behavior? The query is specifying "id", so it should be able to fetch the record instantaneously from index, I would think. And if I remember correctly, when I had the collection as single partition, it was indeed getting result in the first page.
2. If it is (unfortunately) the normal behavior for DocumentDB, what can I do to alleviate the round trip effect? Specifying `x-ms-max-item-count` to a large number like 1000 didn't take any effect. The same record was returning still at 16th page. (As a matter of fact, it seems every record in this collection returns at 16th page...)

As a supplement information, indexing policy is like this :

`{
  "indexingMode": "consistent",
  "automatic": true,
  "includedPaths": [
    {
      "path": "/*",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "kind": "Range",
          "dataType": "Number",
          "precision": -1
        },
        {
          "kind": "Range",
          "dataType": "String",
          "precision": -1
        },
        {
          "kind": "Spatial",
          "dataType": "Point"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "excludedPaths": []
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In DocumentDB, queries that filter on the partition key will be executed in a single hop/partition, but queries that don't have a filter on partition key are executed on every partition (within each partition, the query hits the index).

Note that in partitioned collections, the "primary key" for a document is the compound property of (, "id"), not just "id". For example, if your partition key is "appName", then you should filter on "appName = X" for a single-hop query execution. A query on "appName = X and id = Y" is a primary key lookup.

Also note that with SDK 1.9.0+, DocumentDB supports parallel execution of cross-partition queries. Even when queries do not have a filter on the partition key, parallel query execution allows you to execute queries with very low latency.